# How do I add beveled text effect in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is this possible to add bevel text effect as the image shown here in an app?
I can use images to show beveled text but right now I need to do this programmatically.

[image: Beveled S]

Comment: Please avoid using the "xcode" tag for questions about iOS programming; it should only be used for questions about the IDE itself.

Comment: Ok can you help me with the answer please. Logic will be enough I will do the coding.

Comment: Can you limit to iOS 7 and use letterpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw text with help of

```
   +(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
        inImage:(UIImage*)  image
        atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
   {

       UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
       [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
       CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
       [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
       [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
       UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       return newImage;
    }
```

but make sure you add shadow properly. If needed add more than one text with different shadow.